# Do they support implicit transactions for single DDL statements (CREATE, DROP, ALTER) in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Do they support implicit transactions for single DDL statements (CREATE, DROP, ALTER) in BigQuery? I know some other Cloud database platform only support subset of DDL statements regarding autocommit or single statement transaction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Multi-statement transactions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/transactions) are not generally available yet so each and every statement (DML and DDL) implicitly commit. Even when multi-statement transactions are GA, DDL on permanent objects will implicitly commit and you won't be able to use them in transactions. That's pretty normal:

> DDL statements that create or drop permanent entities, such as datasets, tables, and functions, are not supported inside transactions.

Comment: Thank you Simon. But my question is not about multi-statement transactions but about single statement transaction for DDL SQL statement like (CREATE, DROP, ALTER). If you can let me know whether all or some of them are working, that will be great!

Comment: In my answer I say: "each and every statement implicitly commit". This means that all DDL statements are themselves transactions.